# Google Adsense refuse invocation after X calls

Tags: javascript, adsense

I've developed a script which calls different Adsense ads according to screen size.
the script only issue a 'call' after certain screen size is passed.

However the problem is, the call seems to be refused after a few invocations (3 - 5, depends on how many **other** ads are already on the page), this is what I see on firefox developers console:

GET http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 101ms]

before that I always get:

GET http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 298ms]

Of course, upon refresh everything is ok all over again, until I resize a few times...

My assumption is that this happens because of Google's policy not to show more than 3 ads per page, though this is not the case here since upon resizing, the ads are being inserted instead of one another (.innerHTML).

Any suggestions / workarounds??

Comment: Is this relevant? I doubt a lot of viewers will actually resize their windows.

Comment: first, it makes development much easier. 
second, what difference does it makes to you whether viewrs will use it or not?